# Using AureliaUX on Custom Elements with different values for each instances

Tags: javascript, css, aurelia

I'm trying to use AureliaUX variables in CSS files of Aurelia CustomElement. It works well if each instances have the same value for the variables used in CSS, but I can't make it work with different value for each use of the Custom Elements.

Example of a Custom Element:

```
// View Model
// box.js
import {inject, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {AureliaUX} from 'aurelia-ux';

@inject(AureliaUX)
export class Box {
  @bindable color = '#ff0000';

  constructor(ux) {
    this.ux = ux;
  }

  bind() {
    this.setProperty();
  }

  colorChanged() {
    this.setProperty();
  }

  setProperty() {
    this.ux.design.boxColor = this.color;
  }
}
```

---

```
<!-- View -->
<!-- box.html -->
<template styles.box>
  <require from="./box.css#ux"></require>
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
/* CSS UX File */
/* box.css */
styles.box > div {
  background-color: ${$design.boxColor};
}
```

In my app I then use the Custom Element like this:

```
<template>
    <require from=".../box">
    <box>This box should be red</box>
    <box color="#00ff00">This box should be green</box>
    <box color="#0000ff">This box should be blue</box>
</template>
```

The expected result is to have different color for each box. The current result is that each box get the color of the last defined color property, in this case every boxes are blue.

How can I make it so that the color property is a bindable property and specific to each Box instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a recent push to the Aurelia UX repo that should be in the next release. This exposes the style engine which is what is required to do what you are looking to do with Aurelia UX.

The style engine is what takes the CSS file and processes it with scoped variables that are specific to a component rather than a variable that affects everything across the board as you are experiencing. Using the style engine you can create elements like in the following example.

ux-showcase-figure.ts

```
import {customElement, bindable, ViewResources, View, processAttributes} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {StyleEngine, Themable} from 'aurelia-ux';

@inject(ViewResources, StyleEngine)
@customElement('ux-showcase-figure')
export class UxShowcaseFigure implements Themable {
  @bindable public theme = null;

  public view: View;

  constructor(public resources: ViewResources, private styleEngine: StyleEngine) {}

  public created(_: any, myView: View) {
    this.view = myView;
  }

  public bind() {
    if (this.theme) {
      this.styleEngine.applyTheme(this, this.theme);
    }
  }

  public themeChanged(newValue: any) {
    this.styleEngine.applyTheme(this, newValue);
  }
}
```

ux showcase figure.html

```
<template styles.showcasefigure>
  <require from="./ux-showcase-figure-theme"></require>

  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

ux-showcase-theme.ts

```
import { styles } from 'aurelia-ux';

@styles()
export class UxShowcaseFigureTheme {
  public background: string = '#EEEEEE';
}
```

ux-showcase-theme.css

```
styles.showcasefigure {
  background-color: ${background};
  display: flex;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

styles.showcasefigure > code {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that for the StyleEngine to work, one must require the associated JS file from the view instead of the CSS file (like in your exemple)